# admin.Firebase.Timestamp stores time 7 hours behind

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store a timestamp in Firestore from Firebase Functions. However, the incorrect time is being recorded in Firestore.

For instance, I want to store the UTC time:
August 14, 2021 21hr (9pm)

Note: this code is in my Firebase Function

```
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(
            csvRow.startDateYear,
            csvRow.startDateMonth,
            csvRow.startDateDay,
            csvRow.startDateHour,
            csvRow.startDateMinute
        ))

console.log(date); // prints 2021-08-14T21:00:00.000Z  (correct)

console.log('date.getTime():' + date.getTime()); // prints 1628974800000 (correct)

const timeStamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(date.getTime());

console.log('timeStamp.toMillis():' + timeStamp.toMillis()); // prints 1628974800000 (correct)

write.startDate = timeStamp;
```

But when I actually look at the Firestore and see what's recorded, I get this, a timeStamp that's 7 hours behind:

[image]

I've also tried `Timestamp.fromDate(date)` but got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Firestore TimeStamps break apart when using hours because they do not have timezones built into them. They are meant to represent a greater period of time, not for specific timezones (hour).

Try this function and see if it works properly:

```
var myTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
```

If you are attempting this with Cloud Functions try the following:

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate()
```

Detailed documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: I've already tried `TimeStamp.fromDate(date)` and got the same result. I've updated my question to include this